# Do Perl CGI programs have a buffer overflow or script vulnerability for HTML contact forms?

Tags: perl, security, post, formmail

My hosting company says it is possible to fill an HTML form text input field with just the right amount of garbage bytes to cause a buffer overflow/resource problem when used with Apache/HTTP POST to a CGI-Bin Perl script (such as [NMS FormMail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml)).

They say a core dump occurs at which point an arbitrary script (stored as part of the input field text) can be run on the server which can compromise the site. They say this isn't something they can protect against in their Apache/Perl configuration—that it's up to the Perl script to prevent this by limiting number of characters in the posted fields.  But it seems like the core dump could occur before the script can limit field sizes.

This type of contact form and method is in wide use by thousands of sites, so I'm wondering if what they say is true. Can you security experts out there enlighten me—is this true? I'm also wondering if the same thing can happen with a PHP script.  What do you recommend for a safe site contact script/method?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the buffer overflow, but in any case it can't hurt to limit the POST size anyway. Just add the following on top of your script:

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
$CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * 100;  # max 100K posts
$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 1;  # no uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask them to provide you with a specific reference to the vulnerability. I am sure there are versions of Apache where it is possible to cause buffer overflows by specially crafted POST requests, but I don't know any specific to NMS FormMail.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should ask for specifics from your hosting company. There are a lot of unrelated statements in there.

A "buffer overflow" and a "resource problem" are completely different things. A buffer overflow suggests that you will crash perl or mod_perl or httpd themselves. If this is the case, then there is a bug in one of these components, and they should reference the bug in question and provide a timeline for when they will be applying the security update. Such a bug would certainly make Bugtraq.

A resource problem on the other hand, is a completely different thing. If I send you many megabytes in my POST, then I could eat an arbitrary amount of memory. This is resolvable by configuring the LimitRequestBody directive in httpd.conf. The default is unlimited. This has to be set by the hosting provider.

> They say a core dump occurs at which point an arbitrary script (stored as part of the input field text) can be run on the server which can compromise the site. They say this isn't something they can protect against in their Apache/Perl configuration—that it's up to the Perl script to prevent this by limiting number of characters in the posted fields. But it seems like the core dump could occur before the script can limit field sizes.

Again, if this is creating a core dump in httpd (or `mod_perl`), then it represents a bug in httpd (or `mod_perl`). Perl's dynamic and garbage-collected memory management is not subject to buffer overflows or bad pointers in principle. This is not to say that a bug in perl itself cannot cause this, just that the perl language itself does not have the language features required to cause core dumps this way.

By the time your script has access to the data, it is far too late to prevent any of the things described here. Your script of course has its own security concerns, and there are many ways to trick perl scripts into running arbitrary commands. There just aren't many ways to get them to jump to arbitrary memory locations in the way that's being described here.

Answer (score 0):

Formail has been vulnerable to such in the past so I believe your ISP was using this to illustrate.  Bad practices in any perl script could lead to such woe.

I recommend ensuring the perl script verifies all user input if possible.  Otherwise only use trusted scripts and ensure you keep them updated.

Comment: 'NMS FormMail' ne 'FormMail' from Matt scrpts